# Where do I put HTML fixtures when I'm using JsTestDriver?

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery, js-test-driver

I'm having a hard time getting JSTD to load a fixture HTML file.

My directory structure is:

```
 localhost/JsTestDriver.conf
 localhost/JsTestDriver.jar
 localhost/js/App.js
 localhost/js/App.test.js
 localhost/fixtures/index.html
```

My conf file says:

```
server: http://localhost:4224

serve:

- fixtures/*.html

load: 

- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js
- jasmine/lib/jasmine-1.1.0/jasmine.js
- jasmine/jasmine-jquery-1.3.1.js
- jasmine/jasmine-jstd.js
- js/App.js

test: 

- js/App.test.js
```

My test is:

```
describe("App", function(){

    beforeEach(function(){
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'fixtures';
        loadFixtures('index.html'); **//THIS LINE CAUSES IT TO FAIL**
    });

    describe("When App is loaded", function(){

        it('should have a window object', function(){
            expect(window).not.toBe(null);
        });

    });

});
```

And my console output is:

[image]

([link to full-size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4FNz.png))

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476612/javascript-jstestdriver-jasmine-jasmine-jquery) but it didn't help me figure it out. The weird thing is, when I comment out the

> loadFixtures('index.html');

line, the test passes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay -- figured it out. JsTestDriver prepends "test" to the path to your fixtures.

Also, jasmine-jquery gets fixtures using ajax.

Thus, these steps finally worked for me:

In jsTestDriver.conf:

```
serve:
 - trunk/wwwroot/fixtures/*.html

load:

  - trunk/wwwroot/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js 
  - jstd/jasmine/standalone-1.2.0/lib/jasmine-1.2.0/jasmine.js
  - jstd/jasmine-jstd-adapter/src/JasmineAdapter.js
  - jstd/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js

  - trunk/wwwroot/js/main.js

test:

  - trunk/wwwroot/js/main.test.js
```

In my test file:

```
describe("main", function(){

    beforeEach(function(){
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '/test/trunk/wwwroot/fixtures';
        jasmine.getFixtures().load('main.html');
    });

    describe("when main.js is loaded", function(){

        it('should have a div', function(){
            expect($('div').length).toBe(1); 
        });

    });

});
```

Note that the `beforeEach()` call uses an absolute URL to the HTML fixture.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the fixture path to:

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '/fixtures';
```

I get different, but similarly weird errors otherwise.

Comment: Then I get "Error: Fixture could not be loaded: /fixtures/index.html (status: error, message: undefined)". Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I get that exact error, although sometimes it changes to a browserpanic error

Comment: Hey, Dave -- I added my answer above in case you're still looking.